# How does a Robot respond privately to you in Google Wave?

Tags: bots, google-wave

Google Wave allows two or more participants to speak privately within a wave. When my robot is added to the wave, I recognize the WAVELET_SELF_ADDED event and call the method below.  However, nothing happens.

I can tell that the code is executed because of the Debug and Info statements in the logs.  **Is there any reason why the robot does not start a private blip when it's added?**

```
def start_private_wavelet(properties, context):
    """Start a private conversation between the robot and some participants."""
    participants = []
    participants.append('my-username@googlewave.com')
    participants.append('my-robot@appspot.com')

    logging.debug('Getting wave info')

    root_wavelet = context.GetRootWavelet()
    root_wave_id = root_wavelet.GetWaveId()
    root_wave = context.GetWaveById(root_wave_id)

    logging.debug('Creating private wave in %s' % root_wave_id)

    private_wavelet = root_wave.CreateWavelet(participants)
    message = private_wavelet.CreateBlip()
    message.GetDocument().SetText("This is a private conversation...")

    logging.debug('Private wave created')
```

Comment: I can't find a problem with it. Perhaps try posting the `Outgoing:` operations (from your logs) or trying the Google Wave API group: http://groups.google.com/group/google-wave-api

Comment: Have you seen this working?  I just searched the forum and found a post suggesting that private replies cannot be made through the API: http://bit.ly/7bSMFy

Comment: A Google employee confirmed that this is not possible yet, but will be coming soon.  See the bit.ly link above to track.  Thank you again, Brian, for all of your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A private conversion is created through a Wavelet.

So, using the Python API, I think you're looking for [`OpBasedWave.CreateWavelet`](http://wave-robot-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/waveapi.ops.OpBasedWave-class.html).

```
participants = []
participants.append('other-user@googlewave.com')
participants.append('self-robot@appspot.com') # Remember to add your robot!

private_wavelet = root_wave.CreateWavelet(participants)
message = private_wavelet.CreateBlip()
message.GetDocument().SetText("Hi there, this is just a secret!")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  However, I can't quite get this to work.  I thought I needed to add the line "root_wave = context.GetRootWavelet()" to your code, but that didn't work either.  Perhaps creating a wavelet privately only works with certain events?

Comment: With `context.GetRootWavelet()` you're getting the root __Wavelet__. Now that you have the root Wavelet you can find the root __Wave__ via `root_wave_id = root_wavelet.GetWaveId()` and `root_wave = context.GetWaveById(root_wave_id)`. You can find more information about Wave entities here: http://code.google.com/apis/wave/guide.html#WaveEntities

Comment: I've incorporated your feedback into the question, but the blip is still not created. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I haven't gotten this working yet, but I wanted to accept because this is a great start. Once I find out about the limitations for private replies I will post.